# Increase the size of an image during a collision with pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, size

I have a program with a player (who is an image) and a rectangle and I want that when the player has a collision with the rectangle, the size of the image increase.

---

For now, I have this code :

```
import pygame
from random import randint

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 800
FPS = 60

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
fenetre_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
pygame.display.set_caption("Hagar.io")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

bg = pygame.image.load("bg.png").convert()
bg_surface = bg.get_rect(center=(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2))
bg_x = bg_surface.x
bg_y = bg_surface.y
x_max = WIDTH / 2
y_max = HEIGHT / 2

# player
player = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("player.png").convert_alpha(), (i, i))
player_rect = player.get_rect(center=(x_max, y_max))

# cell
rect_surface = pygame.Rect(300, 500, 20, 20)

# Game loop
running = True
while running:
    dt = clock.tick(FPS) / 1000

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    if player_rect.colliderect(rect_surface):
        print("collide")

    bg_surface.x = bg_x
    bg_surface.y = bg_y

    # draw on screen
    win.blit(bg, bg_surface)
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), rect_surface)
    win.blit(player, player_rect)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

I have try to add in the "colliderect" condition but it does not work :

```
player_rect.width += 1
player_rect.height += 1
```

---

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
player = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("player.png").convert_alpha(), (i, i))
```

is using the variable `i` but it is not defined in your code. I'm not sure where it is defined, but it is **key** to what you want. I will try to answer without this information anyway:

Thing is, enlarging the `rect` won't do anything, because a rect is just coordinates. You have to scale the actual image, and  `pygame.transform.scale` does exactly that.

You can keep the image in a separate variable `player_img`:

```
player_img = pygame.image.load("player.png").convert_alpha()
player = pygame.transform.scale(player_img, (i, i))
```

Then when you want to scale it differently, just call `.scale()` again:

```
double_size_player = pygame.transform.scale(player_img, (i*2, i*2))
```

That still leaves us to the mistery of your undefined `i` variable, but I think you get the gist of it. Remeber that you have to extract a new `rect` from the scaled image because it will be bigger.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the variable i is juste the size of the image (i=60), I have created this variable to do tests..

Comment: @CodingFR ok then just do as in my answer and you can make the image bigger

Comment: I have write this :
`if player_rect.colliderect(rect_surface):
        i += 1
        player = pygame.transform.scale(player_img, (i, i))`

but now, when the size of the player increase, 
it is no longer centered on the window, how can I fix this ?

Comment: @CodingFR You have to recalculate the rect, because, since the images are now bigger, the coordinates have to change. Call `.get_rect()` on each scaled image. A future improvement would be to call multiple `.scale()` at the beginning of the program and store all the bigger player images in a list. That way you don't repeat the scaling all the time, because it can be costly. Then you can just iterate over the list and do the drawing.